# TCL can't find mistake

Tags: tcl

I have some problem in my TCL code.  Please help me to find it. I spent 8 hours already.Thanks

```
set QA1 array()
set QA2 array()
set QA3 array()
set COUNTER1 0
set COUNTER2 0

proc K1Axes { x y z } {
    global QA1
    global QA2
    global QA3
    global COUNTER1

    set fi [expr {2*4*atan(1.)*rand()}]
    set q1 [expr {0.707*cos($fi)}]
    set q2 [expr {0.707*sin($fi)}] 
    set q3 [expr {0.707}]  

    return [list $q1 $q2 $q3]

    set QA1($COUNTER1) [expr {-$q1}]
    set QA2($COUNTER1) [expr {-$q2}]
    set QA3($COUNTER1) [expr {$q3}]
    incr COUNTER1
}


proc K2Axes { x y z } {
    global QA1 
    global QA2
    global QA3
    global COUNTER2 

    set qq1  QA1($COUNTER2)
    set qq2  QA2($COUNTER2)
    set qq3  QA3($COUNTER2)

    return [list $qq1 $qq2 $qq3]

    incr COUNTER2
}
```

Comment: Please specify the nature of the problem you are having and what have you tried so far? This site is not for code review.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too specific.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your script. The first of which is on the first line:

```
set QA1 array()
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. What it does is create a scalar variable (not an array) that contains the seven character string "array()".

Later you try to access it as an array:

```
set qq1  QA1($COUNTER2)
```

This statement should throw an error saying that QA1 is not an array (it is a string after all).

To create an array in tcl, the correct syntax is:

```
array set QA1 {}
```

Please read the Tcl manual for the "array" command for more info about arrays in tcl. Note that if you want to use what other languages call "array" you should be looking at lists instead because tcl arrays are what other languages call "hash" or "map".

Second, you seem to return in the middle of a function. Once returned, all further code that occur after the return statement will not be executed. Hence `QA1($COUNTER1)` is never set.

Comment: I changed my return in the middle of the function. Could you show me how to define a vector and than set up all its elements?

Comment: As mentioned, read the manual for the array command (or if you're just coming from another language, the array "function"): http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/array.htm

Answer (score 1):

Unless your code is incorrect, the `return` statement will cause `K1Axes` and `K2Axes` to return before modifying the globals.  The `return` statement causes the proc to exit immediately.  Nothing after an unconditional `return` is executed.

**Edit**
I also think that you misunderstand arrays in tcl.  Statements like `set QA1 array()` **do not** create an array.  <strike>Try `set QA1()` to create an empty array.</strike> *[I don't know what I was thinking there.]*  Use the [`array` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/array.htm) to manipulate arrays.

Comment: Thanks.I did no know about. I corrected it.But.... I still have mistake

Comment: How do you know, @user1979075? Please add detailed information about the error or incorrect result you're getting to your question.

Comment: -- Error message: can't read "QA1(0)": variable isn't array

Comment: `set QA1()` will complain that it can't read QA1 because the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: You may be tempted to instead do `set QA1() ""` to satisfy `set`. But that's not an empty array. It contains one element "" with the value "" - yes array keys can be anything, even empty strings and binary values.

Comment: How to define empty array? set QA1() doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

### This is correct code.

```
set COUNTER1 0
set COUNTER2 0

proc K1Axes { x y z } {
  global QA1 
  global QA2
  global QA3
  global COUNTER1
  set fi [expr {2*4*atan(1.)*rand()}]  
  set q1 [expr {0.707*cos($fi)}] 
  set q2 [expr {0.707*sin($fi)}] 
  set q3 [expr {0.707}]    
  set QA1($COUNTER1) [expr {-$q1}]
  set QA2($COUNTER1) [expr {-$q2}]
  set QA3($COUNTER1) [expr {$q3}]
  incr COUNTER1
  return [list $q1 $q2 $q3]
}

proc K2Axes { x y z } {
  global QA1 
  global QA2
  global QA3
  global COUNTER2 
  set qq1  $QA1($COUNTER2)
  set qq2  $QA2($COUNTER2)
  set qq3  $QA3($COUNTER2)
  incr COUNTER2
  return [list $qq1 $qq2 $qq3]
}
```